# What is wrong with the revere function?

Tags: django, exception, reverse

Django is throwing me a NoReverseMatch function but I cannot find the reason.

I did check whether I use the reverse function correctly and it seems it does. I also think it is not the custom converters I created because it throws a NoReverseMatch exception.

my forms.py:

```
    #some link creation function
    link = reverse("activate", 
        kwargs={"key":key, "usermail":self.cleaned_data['email']}
        )
    #sending the link to a user
```

root urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
]
```

accounts.urls.py

```
    path('activate/<key:user_key>/<mail:usermail>', 
        views.activate, 
        name="activate"
        ),
]
```

I just expect it to create this wonderful piece of a link and I cannot find what I am doing wrong. Maybe I am looking at the wrong place, maybe it is an integration error, I don't know. Any help is much appreciated.

edit: added the root urls.py

Comment: `"key":` -> `"user_key":`

Comment: Is this base `url.py` ? If no, then please also post the other urls file where this is included until root urls file

Comment: @IvanStarostin: You mean at the reverse function `kwargs={"key":key...`,or in urls.py `key:user_key'`?

Comment: kwarg key is wrong - url pattern contains `user_key` argument, not `key`.

Comment: @Ivan thanks for the explanation. I see now what I did wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **namespace** in your url include

```
path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
```

and in your **forms.py**

```
link = reverse("accounts:activate", 
        kwargs={"user_key":key, "usermail":self.cleaned_data['email']}
        )
```